# Why are my div's overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm not sure why my `<header>` and `<section>` divs are overlapping one another.  I thought that since they were block elements, `<section>` would start below `<header>`.  Any thoughts?  Is there something I need to add in my CSS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Greg's List</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="description" content="This is the challenge     page for the CSS Layout Lesson in Thinkful.  Here I'll be creating a search page for Greg's List">

<!-- reset -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min. css">

<!--styles-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="container">
        <h1 class="title">Greg's List</h1>
        <ul class="links">
            <li class="posts"><a href="#">Post</a></li>
            <li class="account"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav><!--end of nav-->
  </header><!--end of header-->

  <section class="search">
    <form>
        <input class="search-bar">
        <img src="images/magnifying-glass.png" class="search-pic">
    </form>
  </section><!--end of section-->
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: Gainsboro;
 position: fixed;
}


h1 {
    font-family: Arial;
}

.title {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: There's no `div`s in your html... going to be hard to help you without seeing what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Remove position: fixed from header css.

Remember, when you ask question:- Make sure you add the complete code as there is no div in your code

Comment: Sorry, should've said my header and section elements are overlapping.  I'm doing a project for an online course and one of the requirements is that the header be fixed at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I popped your CSS and HTML into this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b19jbasw/1/) but am not seeing any immediate issues.

That being said, I noticed that you have a `float: right;` on your `<ul>` but you don't clear it anywhere, and so this could cause elements to overlap. Assuming you've used floats elsewhere, you need to be sure to `clear:both;` at each level you float elements, like so:

**CSS**

```
.clear {
   clear: both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Greg's List</h1>
    <ul class="links"> <!-- FLOATED ELEMENT -->
        <li class="posts"><a href="#">Post</a></li>
        <li class="account"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>  <!-- CLEAR FLOATS -->
</nav><!--end of nav-->
```

I don't think you've really included enough information (you mentioned overlapping `div` elements, but then posted HTML that didn't contain a single `div`), so I'm shooting in the dark here.

**EDIT:** Check out [Nirjhar Vermani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2226025/nirjhar-vermani)'s answer to your question as well. You have a `position: fixed;` on your header, which I originally assumed was intentional, however this would cause your header to stay in a static position in the window and ignore the elements around it.